# How to remove all non-alphabetic character excluding space using meta character from a string?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to achieve this using meta character?
I can do this by the following regular expression : (note the space in between)

```
s.replaceAll("[^A-Z a-z]","")
```

But how to do this using meta character as I can't implement AND.

Following code obviously doesn't work , but how to do a similar thing?

```
s.replaceAll("\\S&\\d|\\W, "")
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user15793316 , your regex should give the same result as :     s.replaceAll("[^A-Z a-z]","")

Comment: @user15793316 , Thanks it worked , I typed it incorrectly .  Can you explain why it doesn't work with '&' , as it work well with '|' (OR) and '||' is not needed.

Comment: @user15793316 , why we can't use & in 3rd regex ,you shown

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "");
```

To keep number too, you can do:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex, `[^A-Za-z\\s]`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123 & Hello * World!";
        s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
  Hello  World
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^A-Z a-z]` is called a character class (negated here).

`\S`, `\w`, etc. are called shorthand character classes.

You ask if you can match any character different from a letter and space with a shorthand character class.

**The answer is**: there is no such a shorthand class, but there are alternatives:

```java
[^\\p{Alpha} ]
[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{javaSpaceChar}]
[\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{S}]
```